# strange chromedriver fail on os x lion

Tags: osx-lion, selenium-chromedriver

when I try `$chromedriver` on my installation of OS X Lion I get this error message:

```
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.2) on port 9515
objc[5006]: Object 0x1215940 of class NSThread autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
Bus error: 10
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I discovered that `$chromedriver --port=8808` doesn't cause a bus error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an earlier version of Chromedriver (v2.1) and it worked.